# Android: onBackPressed() causes application to crash

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am attempting to use the onBackPressed() method provided by android in order to

The class that I am using the `onBackPressed()` method:

```
import com.interviewme.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Preparing extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preparation);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent t = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(t);

    }
```

}

The part of the manifest file where I am trying to go back to:

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The full manifest file of the app:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.interviewme"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.Play"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PLAY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.Result"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_result" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.interviewme.menu" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.InterviewTips"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.interviewme.Preparing"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error log from logcat:

```
05-09 08:09:43.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 08:09:43.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1741): Process: com.interviewme, PID: 1741
05-09 08:09:43.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1741): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.interviewme/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-09 08:09:43.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1741):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
05-09 08:09:43.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1741):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
http://androidmanifest.xml/
androidmanifest.xml
```

I notice that It states `ActivityNotFound`, however this `Activity` is definitely within my app, is it named incorrectly in manifest?

Comment: instead of this `android:name=".Menu"` write `com.interviewme.Menu` in  manifest and try again.

Comment: This is what I had before and it was still causing the app to collapse

Comment: is your Menu class in same package  ?

Comment: Rename your Menu class to MyMenu, because I think it is problem , you are using reserved Menu name.

Answer (score 2):

its picking android default Menu

remove this line

```
import android.view.Menu;
```

and import your class or change your class name Menu to another name(eg. Menu1)

Answer (score 0):

You imported `android.view.Menu`. Try writing out `com.interviewme.Menu` instead. Also use better names for your activities. Menu is kind of ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Error showing because below:-

```
import android.view.Menu;

Intent t = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(t);
```

Your code pick view.Menu.

you have to use :-

```
Intent t = new Intent(this, com.interviewme.Menu.class);// where menu class here
        startActivity(t);
```